# Remove spacing around rule in latex

Tags: rules

I want to have a rule line that is directly below my line of text. What I am doing is :

```
SomeText Here
\rule{11cm}{0.5pt}
Some text I would like to not disrupt
```

But this adds an extra row between the paragraphs. Using \vspace{-6pt} before or after the rule gives weird and inconsistent results.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Please add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/233#233) and maybe an graph explaining about dislike

Comment: May be `\noindent SomeText Here\\\rule[8pt]{11cm}{0.5pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\par\noindent Some text i would like to not disrupt` ?

Comment: @Fran thanks! That worked beautifully!